# django render to request dict name

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from models import Post
def getRecentPosts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()

    # sort by chronological order
    sorted_posts = posts.order_by('-pub_date')

    # display all posts
    return render_to_response('posts.html', {'posts': sorted_posts})
```

posts.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Django Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for post in posts %}
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <h3>{{post.pub_date}}</h3>
    {{ post.text }}
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

This code works fine & prints the proper data.... However if i change

```
return render_to_response('posts.html', {'posts': sorted_posts})
```

to

```
return render_to_response('posts.html', {'po': sorted_posts})
```

and

```
{% for post in posts %} to {% for post in po %}
```

in posts.html

It fails to generate any data..... So what is the relation between the dictionary name in view and template

Comment: There is no relationship as such. Both should work. It could be due to stale pyc files.

Comment: @karthikr As u said it seems to be some issue with pyc files... Thank you